# ArrayAdapter.createFromResource issue

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to make "Select one" on Spinner. I saw all answer regarding this subject but I am still having some issues. Usual way of making custom spinner is:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter1 =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.entries,
                                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        spinner1.setAdapter(
                  new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapter1,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                                    this));
```

In this code I have to define R.array.entries in Strings.xml, but my app is populating spinner from MySQL and I am having a list `grad[i]=json.getString("Grad");`. How can I create this ArrayAdapter.createFromResource with that list instead of Entries that are defined in Strings.xml? Tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query the data, put it in a `List` or Array and use this constructor of `Array Adapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter1 =  new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayOrList);
```

More here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, java.util.List)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29)

Comment: Can you be more specific, some better explanation, with code if possible? Tnx for effort.

Comment: Cool.  Worked when I was getting error "Wrong 2nd Argument Type.  Required Int."    My adapter was created like this when it wasn't working ``adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.name_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);``