# Why didn't my toast work?

Tags: android, android-toast

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_listview);

    myspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertype);
    String provider = myspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, type_arrays,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener :" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

}
 }
```

---

i tried different kinds of toast but still it wont appear. what went wrong? 
I viewed some posts and it says i cant use onclicklistener to a spinner

Comment: `parent.getContext()` shouldn't it be the `context` of the `Activity`? For example, My `Activity` name is, `MainActivity` **so,  Use**: `MainActivity.this` This should be the `context` of that `Activity`.But i think if you use your own code(`parent.getContext()`) inside the another activity, It won't show up because it's somewhere else actually you know..

Comment: @Mohsen , I do have a listview right below the spinner. did it cover the toast or its just because i use parent.getContext?

Comment: Well, As i saw your codes, Just try to use the current `Activity` context instead of that `parent.getContext()`. Then, If you can't see the `Toast`, You'll have to debug the codes. Also, Could you try to use A SIMPLE TOAST without getting the adapter item? just : `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnItemSelectedListener :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` then let me know if you can see the toast?

Comment: I've explained everything in my answer, Check the answer please. Then let us know what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, Let's check the codes again ;**

Like i said, You'll need to use the current `Activity` `Context`.

> For example, My `Activity` name is, `MainActivity` ***so, Use:
>   `MainActivity.this`*** This should be the context of that `Activity`.But i
>   think if you use your own code(`parent.getContext()`) inside the another
>   activity, It won't show up because it's somewhere else actually you
>   know

Also, You did something wrong here i guess (Something similiar : [ArrayAdapter.createFromResource issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981184/arrayadapter-createfromresource-issue))

**I just quote the answer:**

> Query the data, *put it in a List* or *Array* and use this constructor of
>   [**`ArrayAdapter`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29):

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter1 =  new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayOrList);
```

**Update: So here it is:**

```
Spinner myspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertype);
        String provider = myspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, type_arrays, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                /*ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, type_arrays,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);*/

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnItemSelectedListener :" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Now it should work!

Comment: OHHH MY! it was my mistake. I actually created a new java class. i tried to put the code at my main java list, it worked! thank you

Comment: Good! Glad to heard that. Also, You better to accept an answer for the people who might have the same issue in future..

Answer (score 3):

Have yout try this, that might help you

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener :" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "OnItemSelectedListener :" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: it worked! sorry for the previous comment. it actually depends on where i place the code. thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Try using getContext() instead of getApplicationContext.